# JavaScript calculation output error when combining html documents (html interference?)

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding for a project. I’ve done two separate JavaScript calculations using arrays which add user inputs and provide the sum of it. This is done twice using different textboxes with different ID’s for each calculation.

When I bring both into one html page and open it,  both appear and accept inputs, but only the second one calculates the output and the first output field is blank.

Yet when I open them individually, they both work. 
I’ve searched online for an solution but found none.

Is there a way to still keep them in one html file, but somehow separate them so they don’t interfere with each other ?

As shown in the code below, the calculations use their own ID’s and each element in both calculations have use individual ID’s as well as for all 3 arrays arrays.

Here is the code for the 1st calculation: (its my first time desiging a program so dont judge the mess too harshly)

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('box3');
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  box3.value = myResult;


}

window.sum = () =>
  document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML =
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#txt7,#txt8,#box3')
  ).map(e => parseFloat(e.value) || 0)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#txt7,#txt8,#box3')
  ).map(e => parseFloat(e.value) || 0) // to avoid NaN
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

```css
input[type=text],
select {
  width: 35%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
<h2>Digifix Payment Solutions</h2>
<h3>Payslip Generator</h3>
<p>Section 2: Enter Reneumeration information below.
  <p>

    <body>
      <div>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Reneumeration Information</legend>
            <br></br>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
              <meta charset=utf-8 />
              <title>basic calc</title>
            </head>

            <body>
              <tr>
                Rate of Pay <br></br>
                <td><input id="box1" type="text" placeholder="Enter rate of pay" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
                <br></br> Hours Worked <br></br>
                <td><input id="box2" type="text" placeholder="Enter hours howrke " oninput="calculate()" /></td>
                <br></br> Basic Salary<br></br>
                <td><input id="box3" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td><br></br>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              </table>
            </body>

            </html>
            <script>
            </script>
            <label for="bonus">Bonus:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="txt7" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter bonus ">
            <br></br>
            <label for="ufee">Commision:</label> <br>
            <input type="text" id="txt8" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter earned commission">
            <br></br>
            <script>
            </script>
            <label for="result2">Total Reneumeration:</label> <br> R <span type="text" id="result2"></span>
            <br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Proceed">
        </Form>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The above code exectues and fuctions correctly on its own.

Here is the second code:

```js
window.sum = () =>
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#txt1,#txt2,#txt3,#txt4')
  ).map(e => parseFloat(e.value) || 0)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#txt1,#txt2,#txt3,#txt4')
  ).map(e => parseFloat(e.value) || 0) // to avoid NaN
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

```css
input[type=text],
select {
  width: 35%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
<h2>Digifix Payment Solutions</h2>
<h3>Payslip Generator</h3>
<p>Section 2: Enter deduction information below.
  <p>
    <style>

    </style>

    <body>
      <div>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Deduction Information</legend>
            <br></br>
            <label for="tpercentage">Tax percentage (statistical purpose only)</label> <br>
            <input type="text" id="txt0" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter Tax Percentage" />
            <br></br>
            <label for="tpayable">Tax payable</label> <br>
            <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter Tax Payable">
            <br></br>
            <label for="maid"> Medical Aid Contribution</label> <br>
            <input type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter Medical-Aid contribution">
            <br></br>
            <label for="ufee">Union Fee</label> <br>
            <input type="text" id="txt3" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter Union Fee">
            <br></br>
            <label for="hallowance">Housing Allowance</label> <br>
            <input type="text" id="txt4" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter Housing Allowance">
            <br></br>
            <script>
            </script>
            <label for="result">Total Deductions:</label> <br> R <span type="text" id="result"></span>
            <br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Proceed">
        </Form>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The above code also executes and functions normally alone.

When I put the code onto one combined html doc, only the code positioned last will work correctly and the one positioned first will return the output as blank.

EDIT: find the combnied code below as requested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- CODE 1 -->
<h2>Digifix Payment Solutions</h2>
<h3>Payslip Generator</h3>
<p>Section 2: Enter Reneumeration information below.
<p>
    <style>
        input[type=text], select {
        width:35%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color:gainsboro;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
<div>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Reneumeration Information</legend>
<br></br>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>basic calc</title>
</head>
<body>
<tr>
Rate of Pay <br></br><td><input id="box1" type="text" placeholder="Enter 
rate of pay" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
<br></br> Hours Worked <br></br> <td><input id="box2" type="text" 
placeholder="Enter hours howrke " oninput="calculate()" /></td>
<br></br> Basic Salary<br></br><td><input id="box3" type="text" 
oninput="calculate()" /></td><br></br>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<script>function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('box3');   
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    box3.value = myResult;


      }
</script>
<label for="bonus">Bonus:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="txt7" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter bonus ">
<br></br>
<label for="ufee">Commision:</label> <br>
<input type="text" id="txt8" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter earned commission">
<br></br>
<script>
    window.sum= () => 
     document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML=    
       Array.from(
         document.querySelectorAll('#txt7,#txt8,#box3')
       ).map(e=>parseFloat(e.value)||0)
       .reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
       Array.from(
       document.querySelectorAll('#txt7,#txt8,#box3')
    ).map(e => parseFloat(e.value) || 0) // to avoid NaN
    .reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0)

</script>
<label for="result2">Total Reneumeration:</label> <br>
R <span type="text" id="result2"></span>
<br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Proceed">
</Form>
</div>
</body>
<!-- CODE 2 -->
<h2>Digifix Payment Solutions</h2>
<h3>Payslip Generator</h3>
<p>Section 2: Enter deduction information below.
<p>
    <style>
        input[type=text], select {
        width:35%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color:gainsboro;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
<div>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Deduction Information</legend>
<br></br>
<label for="tpercentage">Tax percentage (statistical purpose only)</label> <br>
<input type="text" id="txt0" onkeyup="sum()"  placeholder="Enter Tax Percentage"/>
<br></br>
<label for="tpayable">Tax payable</label> <br>
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum()"  placeholder="Enter Tax Payable">
<br></br>
<label for="maid"> Medical Aid Contribution</label> <br>
<input type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter Medical-Aid contribution">
<br></br>
<label for="ufee">Union Fee</label> <br>
<input type="text" id="txt3" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter Union Fee">
<br></br>
<label for="hallowance">Housing Allowance</label> <br>
<input type="text" id="txt4" onkeyup="sum()" placeholder="Enter Housing Allowance">
<br></br>
<script>
    window.sum= () => 
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=    
       Array.from(
         document.querySelectorAll('#txt1,#txt2,#txt3,#txt4')
       ).map(e=>parseFloat(e.value)||0)
       .reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
       Array.from(
       document.querySelectorAll('#txt1,#txt2,#txt3,#txt4')
    ).map(e => parseFloat(e.value) || 0) // to avoid NaN
    .reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0)

</script>
<label for="result">Total Deductions:</label> <br>
R <span type="text" id="result"></span>
<br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Proceed">
</Form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show what it looked like when you tried to combine them. Make sure you have the DOCTYPE at the top, and do not duplicate the base tags(html, body, style, script), and I can try to help.

Comment: If your last code sample is the actual piece you are trying then you really really need to clean up your html. Adding 2 body tags can cause issues as you force your browser to interpret what you mean. Also you override your sum function so it doesn't know about the first set of text boxes. You need to refactor your js code if you want it to work properly. Don't just mash stuff together and hope on a star that it works.

Comment: I've seen how the sum function is overridden as they are the same in both arrays. how do i change it so it doesnt clash ? another user below suggested making it window.sum2 etc. but changing the name of the function messes up the code even more, the one that was working stops working.

Comment: If you change the name of the function you have to find the corresponding piece of code that should trigger that function and update it appropriately. You seem like really need to look online for a basic introduction to javascript programming course and review how functions, function calls, and event handlers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the function twice with the same name -> `window.sum`, effectively overwriting it with the second declaration. Change the name and call it accordingly eg. `onkeyup="sum()"`, `onkeyup="sum2()"` etc.

Comment: okay so should i change one of the 2 conflicting names to  window.sum2 , ?

Comment: yes, exactly, or whatever name you choose, just have 2 different names

Comment: but i've leart that since windows.sum is a function, youre not supposed to change its name. can you chang the name of a fuction?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you never declared the variable box3. 
Try solving that first and then on the next post please post the error if you claim you are having one.